# setState during componentDidMount()

Tags: javascript, reactjs, frontend

I start a project with react to improve my skills on it.
But on my project, I have an error when I try to set an array built from a json file in the hook ComponentDidMount(), I think this error has due to a previous one which said :

```
cannot read property 0 of undefined
```

Do I need a specific library to parse the json file correctly?

Below the last error occur :

```
 Can't call setState (or forceUpdate) on an unmounted component.
```

The component which has the method is here :

```
class SimpleMap extends Component{

state={
    positions:[],
    isLoading:true
}
componentDidMount(){
    console.log(data.latlngs);
    this.switchCoord(data.latlngs);
}


switchCoord(datas){
//console.log( datas);
console.log("-----------------");
//remplacer latlngs par data pour fonctionner avec le fichier json
datas.forEach(data =>{
  let newLat;
  let newLng;
  let tableWithNewCoord =[];
  //console.log(data)
  data.forEach(d => {
      newLat = d[1];
      newLng = d[0]; 
      let switchCoordData =[newLat,newLng];
      tableWithNewCoord.push(switchCoordData);
    })
    this.setState({
      positions:[...this.state.positions,tableWithNewCoord]
    })
  })


}
```

The json file is import from the folder assets and it have this form :

```
{
"latlngs":
    [[2.367272,48.662474],[2.36523,48.663373],
    [2.360465,48.66607],[2.3557,48.667419],
    [2.352978,48.667868],[2.348893,48.669217],
    [2.34549,48.671015],[2.342767,48.672813]...]
}
```

thanks in advance for your help.
Best Regards

Comment: How are you importing your data? When calling the function, is `datas` is defined?

Comment: I do my import like that : import data from '../assets/coord.json'. I have data visible in my console.log, so I said yes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that the problem is with your `switchCoord` function. Simply can you try this refactored function of yours:

```
switchCoord(data) //actually data should be renamed to latlngs for readability 
{
  let tableWithNewCoord = [];

  data.forEach( (coord) => {
    tableWithNewCoord.push([coord[1], coord[0]])
  });

  this.setState({positions: tableWithNewCoord});
}
```

Comment: It works but I don't understand my mistake. Could you let me know what was wrong ?

Comment: The first mistake => `datas.forEach(data =>{...` is iterating over the array `[[2.367272,48.662474]....` then your `data.forEach(d => {` is iterating over the `[lat, lng]`. So the `d` actually is not an array it's a value.
The second mistake => `positions:[...this.state.positions,tableWithNewCoord]` which actually result in the position to be [[[lat, lng], ...]] and also it means if you have a value inside position for example position = [2] it will result in this [2, [[lat, lng]...]] is this something you want? that;s why I assgined it directly.

Comment: Thanks for your answer